# Custom User Role Preview Function Not Working

Tags: plugin-development

maybe I need some suggestions how to fix my current problem. I've created a custom user role with the following capabilities:

```
array(
                'read' => true,  // true allows this capability
                'edit_posts' => true,
                'edit_published_posts' => true,
                //'edit_others_posts' => true,
                'publish_posts' => true,
                'upload_files' => true,
                'edit_others_pending_posts' => true,

                'edit_aotm' => true,  //
                'read_aotm' => true,  //
                'read_aotms' => true,  //
                'delete_aotm' => false,  //
                'delete_aotms' => false,  //
                'edit_aotms' => true,  //
                'edit_others_aotms' => false,  //
                'publish_aotms' => false,  //
                'read_private_aotms' => false,  //
                'create_aotms' => false,  //
            )
```

This user role can publish all posts. All other user or user roles (except the admin) only can set the post status to a custom one. So the above user role can publish them. 
The problem now is that the custom user role should can view the preview of this post. At the moment they can only see the preview link. But when they click this preview link (generated from wordpress) they get a 404 error.

With the capability `edit_others_posts` it works, or when the post is published.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why can't they have `edit_others_posts`? That's the capability that determines whether or not they can preview a post that they didn't draft.

Comment: Because they can also edit the post.

Comment: I don’t understand. Are they allowed to edit the posts or not? If so, they need to have edit_posts _and_ edit_others_posts.

Comment: They can edit their own post not from other. But they have to publish all posts they're created from all users.

Comment: WordPress generally expects that if a user can publish a post then they can edit it. How are they supposed to publish the post if they can't open the edit screen?

Comment: Because of the apply the filter. I have generated a custom link to publish a post.